# child-parent components react (sharing)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a link in a particular component...

```
class Bottom extends React.Component {

    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state = {link:"Don't have an account?"}    
    }

    render(){

        return (
        <div>
            <div className="sub-login">
                <p>{this.state.link}<a onClick={this.props.onClick.bind(null, this)}> Register here</a></p>
            </div>

        </div>

        );
    }
}

export default Bottom;
```

I added an onClick event handler on the link above. Now, I want the parent component that uses the component above, `Bottom`, to catch the onClick event.

So in the following component, I want the following...

```
import Bottom from './register-link.js';

class Index extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {header:"Welcome to TutorHub"}
    }

    IF CLICKED: console.log("link was clicked");

    render(){   
        return (
        <div>

                <Inputs />   
                <Bottom />    

            </div>


        </div>

        );
    }
}

export default Index;
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the official documentation of react js you can pass functions and values as props from parent to children component. Just pass a function as props named **onClick** to the Bottom component from the Index component. It will be

```
<Bottom onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)}/>
```

instead of

```
<Bottom />
```

The Full code is given bellow:

```
class Bottom extends React.Component {

    constructor(){
        super();

        this.state = {link:"Don't have an account?"}    
    }

    render(){

        return (
        <div>
            <div className="sub-login">
                <p>{this.state.link}<a onClick={this.props.onClick.bind(this)}> Register here</a></p>
            </div>

        </div>

        );
    }
}

export default Bottom;


import Bottom from './register-link.js';

class Index extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {header:"Welcome to TutorHub"}
        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
    }
    handleClick()
    {
      console.log("link was clicked");
    }


    render(){   
        return (
        <div>

                <Inputs />   
                <Bottom onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)}/>    

            </div>


        </div>

        );
    }
}

export default Index;
```